# Why Proguard runs despite having minifyEnabled in gradle config?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

According to documentation setting minifyEnabled to false must disable ProGuard run

```
    integration {
        minifyEnabled false
        versionNameSuffix "-int"}
```

But the ProGuard is still started by Gradle! Any ideas why?

Comment: The ProGuard is invloved in the step :control:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForIntegration

Comment: related : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199630

Answer (score 0):

You will need to **change the Build Variant** to use one of the `integration` build variants (from the bottom left in android studio), if you want to use the configuration for `integration` buildType.

From what you describe you appear to be using a different buildType. By default it is debug. Make sure an integration Build Variant is selected and you should be good.

[image]

Comment: No, I have proper build Variant running

Comment: are you also using build flavors?

Answer (score 0):

As it often happens, I found and answer after posting my question.

"This is not a bug, this is a feature":

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/adt-dev/iS_lyRH8hL8

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a problem, but certainly annoying.

The output you are seeing is related to the way the Android gradle plugin determines the set of classes that must be in the main dex file when multidex is enabled. For this purpose it uses ProGuard internally, but it is unrelated to your configuration.

In order to disable the logging output of this task, you can add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
  if (task.name.startsWith("transformClassesWithMultidexlistFor")) {
    task.logging.level = LogLevel.ERROR
  }
}
```